# Python: permission to change file only through the script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote an application that creates csv file using with open and changes them according to users choises.
I want restrict the files so the users won't be able to open the files outside the software (on excel or any other program) and change them (content and file characteristics) through those softwares, without restricting the ability to change the files through my software.

thanks,
Lior

Comment: look at [`os.chmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chmod). You can change permission to `stat.S_IWRITE` in your script, write to it and then change permission to `stat.S_IREAD` to make it read only. But user can with enough privileges(eg. administrator) can remove the read_only flag from csv and edit it. If a csv file is on user's PC, you can not make it impossible for the user to edit it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't really do this with a `.csv` because the operating system controls that sort of access. You can make the file read-only, and have your program change the read-only flag before processing it. But your user will be able to defeat that. Realistically, you have three options:

1. You can encrypt the file so that only your code understands it.
2. You can calculate a hash of the file and store it. When your code opens the file it can check the hash and refuse to process it if the file has been changed.
3. You can switch to storing your data in a database. Databases have the sort of access control that you want. For example, your program can have a username/password combination that only it knows.